# Result Giving Back Empty String for Integration Test

Tags: java, integration-testing, integration, return-value

I've been looking around online and I can't seem to find a solution for my problem. I have an integration test as shown below that is supposed to return the String "Lossrates calculated successfully" but instead returns a <[]> blank string.

```
    @Test
public void test() throws Exception {

    String name = "mockName";
    String date = new Date().toString();

    LossrateRequest lossrateRequest = new LossrateRequest();
    lossrateRequest.setAsOfDate(new Date().toString());
    lossrateRequest.setName(name);

    Date asOfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy").parse(date);
    boolean testStatus = lossrateRequest.getName().isEmpty();

    String expected = "Lossrates calculated successfully.";

    Mockito.when(lossrateCalculationService.calculateHistory(name, asOfDate)).thenReturn(testStatus);
    Mockito.when(lossrateService.saveGenerated(name, asOfDate, lossrateService.numOfRowsInHistoricalLoss()))
            .thenReturn(testStatus);

    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/historical-loss/generate")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();

    assertEquals(expected, result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
}
```

I am figuring its happening due to the `MvcResult` line but everywhere online has the `andReturn()` blank as I do so I'm not sure why its returning blank.

Comment: What is the `mockMvc` variable?

Comment: Its just a private variable. I have it @Autowired in as a private MockMvc mockMvc. It is apart of the mock package for unit tests and integration tests.